# Assembly-Natural numbers division program

Tags: assembly, lc3

I need to make a program at LC3 assembly that devides 2 natural numbers and stores the remainder at R0.In case that R1 is zero,R1 must be 0.Else R1 must be 1.
My code is:

```
.ORIG X3000
       LD R0,DIVIDED
       LD R1,DIVIDER
       BRZ IMPOSSIBLE
       ADD R2,R2,#1   
       NOT R4,R1
       ADD R4,R4,#1  ;r4=-r1       
LOOP   ADD R3,R0,R4  ;r3=ro-r1
       BRN FINISH
       ADD R0,R3,#0   ;ro=ro-r1
       BRNZP LOOP
IMPOSSIBLE  LD R2,ZERO
            BRNZP FINISH
FINISH HALT

DIVIDED .FILL #25

DIVIDER .FILL #4
 .END
```

This is my first program at LC3 assembly...I am a total beginner.Could anyone explain to me why this doesn't compile?I always get a "Invalid label '#25" "error message.Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try to omit the `#` sign from the `.FILL` directives.

Comment: Or try making the numbers hex (eg. x0019 for 25 and x0004 for 4)

Comment: Well,I tried x0019 and x0004 but still,it doesn't compile unfortunately.

Comment: What is the error with those numbers? "Invalid label x0019" ? Or something different?

Comment: The same error..Invalid label x0019

Comment: it compiled for me when I added "ZERO .FILL x0000" at the bottom

Comment: I just tried "ZERO.FILL x0000"  as well...No different result unfortunately..

Comment: Is zero defined in your code? Why not use #0 there instead?

Comment: Which assembler version are you using?

Comment: Your code works for me as long as I deal with the ZERO problem. I used http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0072467509/student_view0/lc-3_simulator.html (Windows)

Comment: My program just worked.I really just can't belive in my eyes!I just changed the names of the labels...Instead of DEVIDER I wrote ZERO and instead of devided ONE.How can this be?I still give the same values, #4 and #25.I have an LC3 assembler.

Comment: I would be grateful if anyone could explain this to me,as I will definitely need it in future programs..In any case ,thank you for your time and help!